# Animate views before activity finished

Tags: android, android-animation

I use view animations in a predrawlistener to animate the activity start.

Exist a similar listener to animate my views before my activity is finished?

I know the `overridependingtransition` method for animations in xml but i want to use `ViewPropertyAnimations` in a programmatically way for specific views.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to override [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) method, then add your animation there:

```
@Override
public void finish (){
    // do your animation
    super.finish();
}
```

You can call  `YourActivity.finsih();` when you want to finish your activity from code.